adafruit_platformdetect board.py pin mapping
Simply: I'm trying to find what physical pin on the Raspberry PI 4B that attributes like board.D5 map to.
QUESTIONS:

Can I simply get or create a mapping of the board.py pin attributes to actual physical pins? I.e. board.D5 = ?

If not, I need to figure out what board.py attribute is associated with pin 33 (GPIO 23, PWM1)?



DETAILS:
I'm using the kiln-controller.py software from here. The code was working fine with an older Pine64a, but I'm converting to a Raspberry Pi 4B. kiln-controller.py uses the Adafruit_Python_PlatformDetect board.py to configure the input and output pins.
I have the thermocoupler working - but the pinouts do not seem to correspond to the instructions in the project page.

The kiln-controller's config.py file is setting the MAX31855-CS to board.D5.
With CS = board.D5 and MY wiring (with CS physically connected to GPIO21 GPCLK1 PIN29)- the thermocoupler works ... which leads me to believe that board.D5 != GPIO5.
Ultimately, the point of all this is that the config.py also sets the signal output to the kiln heater control as gpio_heat = board.D23. The output wire is physically attached to pin33 (GPIO 23, PWM1.) But with gpio_heat = board.D23 the wire is getting no signal out. How can I find which board.X pin to use in the config file for pin 33?
config.py
# To control the kiln, one gpio pin is used as an output. Pick any 
# you like. I chose gpio pin 23. This output is used to control a
# zero-cross solid-state-relay.
try:
    import board
    spi_sclk  = board.D11 #spi clock
    spi_mosi  = board.D10 #spi Microcomputer Out Serial In (not connected) 
    spi_miso  = board.D9  #spi Microcomputer In Serial Out
    spi_cs    = board.D5  #spi Chip Select
    gpio_heat = board.D23 #output that controls relay
except NotImplementedError:
    print("not running on blinka recognized board, probably a simulation")



Ask Adafruit for documentation and why they want to use this obscure code.

It looks as if your board.<n> IS associated with GPIO <n>. You can deduce this from Raspberry Pi's SPI0 port. This is on GPIO pins 9, 10 and 11:
- GPIO 10 (SPI0 MOSI) 19
- GPIO 9 (SPI0 MISO) 21
- GPIO 11 (SPI0 SCLK) 23

It corresponds with your:
spi_sclk  = board.D11 #spi clock  
spi_mosi  = board.D10 #spi Microcomputer Out Serial In (not connected)   
spi_miso  = board.D9  #spi Microcomputer In Serial Out  

I have added this pinout from raspberrypi.com in response to your comments, and you can see from this that GPIO5 is pin 29 - so board.D5 DOES correspond to GPIO5 (and the fact that CS on pin 29 works as intended proves it).


Perhaps. I did find this: https://learn.adafruit.com/circuitpython-essentials/circuitpython-pins-and-modules which describes how to figure out which physical pins are associated with the board.Ax or board.Dx objects. They provide a script code.py which is supposed to enumerate it - but it seems to only work in CircuitPython - which I'm trying to figure out on the RPi4b. However, in your answer above you show SPI0 MOSI as pin 19 (correct) but GPIO 10 (incorrect according to the diagram I got from the RPi4B schematics page. 

I'm also curious as to why pin 18 (GPIO5) does NOT work with the thermocoupler when the config says spi_cs = board.D5 #spi Chip Select, but DOES work when I attach the CS cable to GPIO21/GPclk1/Pin29?

What do you mean by: 'but GPIO 10 (incorrect according to the diagram I got from the RPi4B schematics page. '?

Sorry for the confusion. So, in the image above Raspberry Pi 4 Model B (J8 header) (which I screenshot'ted from the RPi schematics page) is shows MOSI(SPI) as physical pin 19, but marks it as GPIO12 (not GPIO10.) In addition, the thermocoupler [TC]  config file has CS-->board.D5. If I plug CS into GPIO5 (physical pin 18) the TC does NOT work. If I plug CS into GPIO21 (GPCLK1, physical pin 29) the TC works. Making me think board.D5 can't be GPIO5.

This is because your pinout map has to be wrong. I have added a pinout from raspberrypi.com to my answer, and you can see from this that GPIO5 is pin 29 - so board.D5 DOES correspond to GPIO5 (and the fact that CS on pin 29 works as intended proves it).

That makes sense. Thanks! Can you link where you got this image, so I can bookmark it?

Cool. It is at: https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html.
